# How to get an access to project inside Ubuntu subsystem on Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed Ubuntu subsystem on Windows 10 and I'm happy. Everything works fine. But I have a problem. I wanted to edit my NodeJS project by Webstorm which I have on Windows, is that even possible?

Comment: If it is in `C:\MyProject` then use `/mnt/c/MyProject` folder in WSL. Path is case sensitive in WSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. I've been working like this for the past year or so. I use WSL to do all my git, npm, and node operations and webstorm/vs code/sublime to edit the files natively on windows.

There are a couple of points to be careful with:

1. Ensure you are saving files with unix line endings
2. Make sure you are working on files inside the `/mnt/c/....` folders. If you change files elsewhere inside the WSL from windows you can seriously mess things up as files that live in other locations require linux meta data. Basically put, things will not go well for you.